# How can I describe mutable strings when strings are immutable by default?

Tags: ruby, string, literals, ruby-2.3

When a file has the pragma:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

all strings written as literals in that file are frozen by default. When I want my strings to be immutable overall, and hence am using the pragma, but want to have a couple of mutable strings, what is the recommended way to write them?

All I can think of is:

```
String.new("foo")
```

Comment: Was just going to say `dup` too. It's just that this is the cool new stuff and the community doesn't have a convention on it yet.

Comment: @ndn I don't care about convention. What matter is conciseness, readability, performance, etc.

Comment: there is no new syntax like `"foo"u` if that is what you are asking. You can't get more concise than `Object#dup`. As for performance, I would be surprised if `String.new` is significantly better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had missed it. The recommended way is to use the `+@` method string literal.

```
(+"foo").frozen? # => false
(-"foo").frozen? # => true
"foo".frozen? # => true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `dup` the literal to make it mutable:

```
"foo".dup.frozen? # => false
```